# (Delphi FMX) How do I use Canvas.FillText to show up in the middle of an Ellipse?

Tags: delphi, canvas, firemonkey

I want to show numbers in the middle of an Ellipse as text drawn on a canvas. The coordinates will be stored (for the ellipse) inside of a database, as well as the text value will be stored in another part of a database.

What I have done so far is I have been working w/ a demonstration project (DrawApp) from [FMXExpress (Github)](https://github.com/FMXExpress/Firemonkey/blob/master/FMXExpress/DrawApp/MyPaintBox.pas) where I have changed a few procedures from being Private to Public. These procedures include StartDrawing(startP:TPointF), EndDrawing(startP:TPointF), DoDraw() that way I can use these functions from the external Unit/Object. The object uses these functions in coordination with MouseUp/MouseDown, as well as few properties including fDrawing to distinguish whether or not drawing is in progress, and just what tool is being used (fdEllipse).

My Main form uses the following code inside the FormCreate to initially create the fdrawbox := TMyPaintBox.Create(Rectangle1); The Rectangle1 sits on top of an image, which represents a grid to show a body part, and will be able to draw circles on top of the image. What I have found is that it is not hard to create either the text or the ellipse, but for the purpose of creating multiple circles with an identifier to distinguish circles, as I have mentioned, I want to have a number to show up which circle is which. And even in the future, I may want to change the colour to show which circle to concentrate on.

[demonstration for mypaintbox http://www.abatepain.com/abate/OHlbF.jpg](http://www.abatepain.com/abate/OHlbF.jpg)

So the following code (Delphi FMX) shows creating a drawapp by utilising a TRectangle as its parent.

```
with fdrawbox do begin
  Parent := Rectangle1;
  Visible := True;
  ForegroundColor := TAlphaColor($FF000000); //
  BackgroundColor := TAlphaColor($00000000); //

  FuncDraw := TFunctionDraw.fdEllipse; //fdrawbox.fDrawing := True;
  StartDrawing(PointF(100, 100));
  EndDrawing(PointF(200, 200));
  FuncDraw := TFunctionDraw.fdNone;

  OnPaint := PaintBox1Paint;
end;
```

The circle is created using the last few lines, but in order to utilise FillText, I need to use a OnPaint Function, which I created and the code looks something like this. I believe that DrawApp handles OnPaint function internally, but just how it handles it is still unknown. But it is never the less a necessity in order to print "Hello Text!!"

```
procedure TMainForm.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
begin
  with Canvas do begin
    BeginScene();
    //Clear(cbbg.Color);
    Font.Style := [];
    Font.Size := 12;
    Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Red;
    FillText(TRectF.Create(0, 0, 300, 295), 'Hello Text!!', false, 100, [], TTextAlign.Center, TTextAlign.Center); //TFillTextFlag.RightToLeft
    EndScene;
  end;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Can someone give an example of how to handle this (possibly inside a single function) where I can print multiple circles and have the associated text follow with it? I believe with the previous example, I could do it on my own, but that I would have to manually enter the PointF (for the circle) and TRectF for the Text, and they both use different values as coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noted, the `TMyPaintBox` class doesn't support text rendering, nor properties often used with text output like font or color etc. But you can add those yourself by defining fields in the private section and the properties to get/set the values in the public section.

In the following I assume addition of fields `ftextout`, `ffontsize` and `ffontcolor` with corresponding properties `TextOut` `FontSize` and `FontColor`.

To add functionality for rendering text in the similar way other element types are drawn, add `fdText` as a new enum to `TFunctionDraw`.

```
  TFunctionDraw=(fdNone,fdPen,fdLine,fdRectangle,fdEllipse,fdFillBgr,fdBitmapStamp,fdPolyLine, fdText);
```

Then in `TMyPaintBox.DoDraw` add a new case option to `case ffdraw of` like for example:

```
with vCanvas do
begin
BeginScene();
case ffdraw of 
  //
  // other TFunctionDraw enums
  //
  TFunctionDraw.fdText: begin
    {Canvas.}Font.Size := ffonsize; // new field
    {Canvas.}Fill.Color := ffontcolor; // new field 
    {Canvas.}FillText(r, TextOut, False, 1, [],
      TTextAlign.Center, TTextAlign.Center);
  end;
end;
```

**Edit:**

The references to `Canvas` in the `TFunctionDraw.fdText` are superfluous. Remove the outcommented references. The canvas to use is already defined in a `with` statement (added to the code to show). Oh, I hate those `with`s!

It is also worth to notice, that if you only want to display circles with text, and not let the user draw on the canvas, you could achieve it much simpler with a component of your own make.

Also, do not call `DoDraw` directly. It is called by `Paint` which is fired whenever the `fdrawbox` is invalidated. So, call `invalidate` instead when you want to force an update.

**End of edit**

Then you can achieve text rendering just as any other drawing of elements (using your code template):

```
with fdrawbox do begin
  Parent := Rectangle1;
  Visible := True;
  ForegroundColor := TAlphaColor($FF000000); //
  BackgroundColor := TAlphaColor($00000000); //

  FuncDraw := TFunctionDraw.fdEllipse; //fdrawbox.fDrawing := True;
  StartDrawing(PointF(100, 100));
  EndDrawing(PointF(200, 200));

  FuncDraw := TFunctionDraw.fdText;
  FontSize := 12; // set new property
  FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Red; // set new property
  TextOut := 'Hello text!';
  StartDrawing(PointF(100, 100));
  EndDrawing(PointF(200, 200));

  FuncDraw := TFunctionDraw.fdNone;

  invalidate;
  // OnPaint := PaintBox1Paint; // no need for this
end;
```

Comment: I appreciate your Answer, so thank you. But I am receiving a Access Violation. I started a new project to be sure it wasn't a hidden problem in my code. Project1.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x0077dbdc: read of address 0x00000000' I corrected a couple of font property spellings aka ffonsize, and have taken a screen grab. [link](https://postimg.org/image/cdpak9yw1/)  I also tried pre-defining the values inside the Create() function in MyPaintBox.pas, but that didn't work. I also tried initiating the start/enddrawing at different points,

Comment: @Barry On which is the AV triggered? Your screen grab link shows only "This page can not be displayed".

Comment: These are also my properties that I have added. I believe the error message has to do with the data type I have chosen for TextOut. 
    property TextOut:string read ftextout write ftextout;
    property FontSize:Single read ffontsize write ffontsize;
    property FontColor:TAlphaColor read ffontcolor write ffontcolor;  [link](https://s32.postimg.org/u0cgfamdh/delphi_exception_error.jpg)

Comment: I just tried using a regular string (text), instead of TextOut, within the ffdraw case, but the error message continues to shows up.  [link](https://s32.postimg.org/u0cgfamdh/delphi_exception_error.jpg)  I don't know why the screen grab did not work at first, but I hope this one works.

Comment: @Barry I can now confirm the error, but I need some time to solve it. A little busy now, so it may take until tomorrow.

Comment: @Barry I have edited my answer and corrected the code.